# Why needs syntax highlighting often a `revert-buffer`?

Tags: python, font-lock, syntax, revert-buffer

Quite frequently, syntax highlighting in a given buffer is broken (i.e., a big fraction of the code is not highlighted).  This is definitely not due to syntax errors, and the point at which highlighting stops quite often is in the middle of an identifier.  Then, a `revert-buffer` regularly restores the highlighting.  Of course, it is annoying to be forced to do so over and over again.  What is the root cause of this, and how can one make the syntax highlighting more robust?

I observe this on python-mode buffers since I program almost exclusively in that language, but I have observed this in other modes, too.

Comment: Background information is missing here. What is your `emacs-version` (get value with `M-x emacs-version RET`? It looks like a bug as you describe it and therefore `emacs-version` can be relevant here. What is your `system-type` (get value with `C-h v system-type RET`)? Also the terminal type can be relevant for the question: `M-: (terminal-name) RET`. It would also be good if you added a minimal example where you observe the effect together with a recipe for problem reconstruction starting with `emacs -Q`.

Comment: What @Tobias said. If you see this with `emacs -Q` then please provide a step-by-step recipe to reproduce it. If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: I will have a look at whether thinning out my `.emacs` helps. That said, I observe this problem since I use Emacs – this is since 2001.

Answer (score 2):

When there is an error in the syntax highlighting code, it is silently ignored by the font-lock package. When this happens, the buffer can be left in an unhighlighted state.

You can use the package [font-lock-studio](https://github.com/Lindydancer/font-lock-studio) to investigate what happens, and catch errors in the font-lock code. It is a debugger that lets you step each part of the font-lock rules and if any rule triggers an error, the normal elisp debugger is invoked.